# C# mono CPU and RAM usage

Tags: c#, mono, ram, cpu

На mono не хочет работать следующий код:

```
        var cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter();

        cpuCounter.CategoryName = "Processor";
        cpuCounter.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
        cpuCounter.InstanceName = "_Total";

        Console.WriteLine (cpuCounter.NextValue()+"%");
```

Всё время один результат: 0%

Есть ли другие способы получить информацию о нагрузках CPU и RAM, или как исправить мой код?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по [этой  доке](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.aspx) и [этой](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.nextvalue.aspx):

> the first read operation returns 0.0

Чтобы там был не 0, надо вызывать метод более одного раза:

```
    var cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter();

    cpuCounter.CategoryName = "Processor";
    cpuCounter.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
    cpuCounter.InstanceName = "_Total";

    Console.WriteLine (cpuCounter.NextValue()+"%"); // здесь 0
    Console.WriteLine (cpuCounter.NextValue()+"%"); // а здесь уже нет
```